# Not able to exit app react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am facing problem exiting from a react native app on Android. Usually, it works well on pressing back button of android on the home screen it exits the app. But there are social media icons on the home page when I click on them, it opens the app i.e Instagram or twitter and when I come back to the react native app, it goes into a loop, just rerendering again and again. I am using Linking to open social media apps and Stack Navigator to navigate.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  Linking,
  BackHandler,
  ScrollView,
  AppState
} from 'react-native';
import AndroidBackButton from "react-native-android-back-button"

var { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-smart-splash-screen'
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';
const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\nCmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\nShake or press menu button for dev men' +
  'u'
});



// screen related book keeping

import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        appState: AppState.currentState,
    }
}

  componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.close({ animationType: SplashScreen.animationType.fade, duration: 2000, delay: 500 })                                     
  }


  render() {
    console.log("rendering");
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    var id;
    if (params) {
      id = params.index;
    }
    else
      id = 0
    return (
      <Swiper index={id} loop={false} showsButtons={false}>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-bHyvuO7S2D0/WeWEb_Q0_wI/AAAAAAAAAAc/KKprxCXMoAYJZTyfSlO2wl5hyEvvz7qdwCK8BGAs/s512/backroundapp.jpg'
          }}
          style={{
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: 'center',
            resizeMode: "stretch",
            height: height - 20,
            width: width
          }}>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(32,36,100,1)" barStyle="light-content" />
          <View style={styles.outerView}>
            <Image
              style={{
                height: 125,
                width: 125
              }}
              source={require('../images/logo.png')} />
            <View
              style={{
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginTop: 70,
                flexDirection: 'row'
              }}>
              <View style={styles.column}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={.5}
                  onPress={() => {
                    //BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);                        
                    navigate("LiveTV")
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../images/live.png')}
                    style={{
                      resizeMode: "stretch",
                      height: 250,
                      width: 250
                    }} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginTop: 10,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: "#FFF"
                  }}>Live TV</Text>

              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          {/* <AndroidBackButton
            onPress={this.handleBackButton}
          /> */}
        </Image>

        <Image                                                                
          source={{
            uri: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-bHyvuO7S2D0/WeWEb_Q0_wI/AAAAAAAAAAc/KKprxCXMoAYJZTyfSlO2wl5hyEvvz7qdwCK8BGAs/s512/backroundapp.jpg'
          }}
          style={{
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: 'center',
            resizeMode: "stretch",
            height: height - 20,
            width: width
          }}>
          {/* <AndroidBackButton
            onPress={this.handleBackButton}
          /> */}
          <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(32,36,100,1)" barStyle="light-content" />
          <View style={styles.outerView}>
            <Image
              style={{
                height: 125,
                width: 125
              }}
              source={require('../images/logo.png')} />
            <View
              style={{
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginTop: 30,
                flexDirection: 'row'
              }}>
              <View
                style={styles.column}
              >
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={.5}
                  onPress={() => {
                    //BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);                        
                    navigate("AudioPage")
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../images/icon.png')}
                    style={{
                      resizeMode: "stretch",
                      height: 55,
                      width: 55
                    }} /></TouchableOpacity>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginTop: 10,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: "#FFF",
                    textAlign: 'center'
                  }}>Audio</Text>

                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={.5}
                  onPress={() => {
                    //BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);                        
                    navigate("FacebookPage")
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../images/facebook-logo.png')}
                    style={{
                      marginTop: 20,
                      resizeMode: "stretch",
                      height: 55,
                      width: 55
                    }} /></TouchableOpacity>

                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginTop: 10,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: "#FFF"
                  }}>Facebook</Text>
              </View>
              <View
                style={styles.column}
                style={{
                  marginLeft: 100
                }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={.5}
                  onPress={() => {
                    //BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);                        
                    navigate("YoutubePlaylist")
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../images/youtube.png')}
                    style={{
                      alignSelf: 'center',

                      marginTop: 10,
                      resizeMode: "stretch",
                      height: 55,
                      width: 55
                    }} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: "#FFF"
                  }}>Video</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={.5}
                  onPress={() => {
                    //BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);                        
                    navigate("Gallery")
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../images/gallery.png')}
                    style={{
                      alignSelf: 'center',
                      marginTop: 20,
                      resizeMode: "stretch",
                      height: 55,
                      width: 55
                    }} /></TouchableOpacity>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginTop: 10,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: "#FFF"
                  }}>Pictures</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                marginTop: 20
              }}>
              <View
                style={styles.column}
                style={{
                }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={.5}
                  onPress={() => {
                    //BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);                        
                    navigate("ContactPage")
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../images/contact.png')}
                    style={{
                      resizeMode: "stretch",
                      height: 55,
                      alignSelf: 'center',
                      width: 55
                    }} /></TouchableOpacity>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 20,
                    marginTop: 10,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    color: "#FFF"
                  }}>Contact</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginTop: 40 }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                console.log("Clicked On Whatsapp");
                Linking.canOpenURL('http://instagram.com/_u/dhadrian.wale/').then(supported => {
                  if (supported) {
                    Linking.openURL('http://instagram.com/_u/dhadrian.wale/');
                  } else {
                    Toast.show('No app installed to open this link', Toast.LONG);
                  }
                });
              }}>
                <Image style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }} source={require('../images/insta.png')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                console.log("Clicked On Whatsapp");
                Linking.canOpenURL('http://twitter.com/parmeshar_tv/').then(supported => {
                  if (supported) {
                    Linking.openURL('http://twitter.com/parmeshar_tv/');
                  } else {
                    Toast.show('No app installed to open this link', Toast.LONG);
                  }
                });
              }}>
                <Image style={{ width: 40, height: 40, marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 30 }} source={require('../images/tweet.png')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                console.log("Clicked On Whatsapp");
                Linking.canOpenURL("mailto:?to=emm.pee.ldh@gmail.com").then(supported => {
                  if (supported) {
                    Linking.openURL("mailto:?to=emm.pee.ldh@gmail.com");
                  } else {
                    Toast.show('No app installed to open this link', Toast.LONG);
                  }
                });
              }}>
                <Image style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }} source={require('../images/email.png')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Image>
      </Swiper>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  column: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  outerView: {
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: -25,
    height: height - 75,
    width: width - 25,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(32,36,100,0.5)',
    borderRadius: 10
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: show some related code for better understanding

Comment: Please check I have added home screen code